# Как сделать чтобы modelformset_factory показывал поле из модели, но не давал его редактировать

Tags: django

Есть такая модель:

```py
class user_accounts(models.Model):
    user123 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    acc_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    online_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kill_beast = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Я рисую форму:

```py
user_settings_form_unfiltred1 = modelformset_factory(user_accounts, exclude=('user123',), extra=0, )
form1 = user_settings_form_unfiltred1(queryset=user_accounts.objects.filter(user123=request.user))
```

В этом варианте на странице отрендерится форма из трех строк (или более кратно 3), но я не хочу, чтобы пользователь имел возможность редактировать поле 'acc_name', но не показать его я тоже не могу, так как тогда пользователю не совсем понятно для какого из  acc_name он меняет другие настройки, особенно это актуально когда 
`queryset=user_accounts.objects.filter(user123=request.user)` вернет несколько инстансов модели. И отрендерится 6 или 9 строк формы.

Answer (score 0):

Я придумал частичное решение проблемы:

```py
def update_user_settings(request):
    user_settings_form_unfiltred = modelformset_factory(user_accounts, exclude=('user123',) , extra=0, )
    user_settings_form_unfiltred1 = modelformset_factory(user_accounts, exclude=('user123',), extra=0, )
    form1 = user_settings_form_unfiltred1(queryset=user_accounts.objects.filter(user123=request.user))

    s=[]
    for i in form1:
        a = i.__dict__
        s.append(a)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_settings_form_unfiltred(request.POST, queryset=user_accounts.objects.filter(user123=request.user))

        z=0
        for i in form:
            user_settings=s[z]['instance']
            z = z + 1
            if i.is_valid():
                user_settings.kill_beast =i.cleaned_data['kill_beast']
                user_settings.online_status = i.cleaned_data['online_status']
                user_settings.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('settings') )

    else:
        form = user_settings_form_unfiltred(queryset=user_accounts.objects.filter(user123=request.user))

    return render(request, 'catalog/user_accounts_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Я создаю две одинаковых формы, но отображаю только одну. Потом из отображенной пользователю формы передаю только нужные мне данные в не отображенную форму и сохраняю не отображенную форму. При этом не важно внесет пользователь изменения в "acc_name" или нет, они все равно не сохранятся.
Я практически уверен, что так делать не правильно, но я недавно начал учить django и лучшего решения проблемы пока не нашел.